# install ubuntu in samsung chromebook

Tags: software-installation

Help me friends.How can I install ubuntu on my samsung chromebook 3. It has 16GB of internal memory, 4 GB of RAM and the processor is an intel celeron

Answer (score 0):

After doing some quick searching there is an application called Crouton, which allows one to easily run both Ubuntu and Chrome OS on the computer at the same time. This is not a dual boot setup, Crouton runs a "container" in Chrome OS that is Ubuntu. Here is a tutorial from Ubuntu on it. However, to install Ubuntu and not with Chrome OS would take some time and effort and found the video below that seems decent.[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=629&v=AxsckwmRhfw) [Crouton](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#0)